# Node.js Express: Weird Characters in response to download XLSX Attachment

Tags: node.js, excel, express, xlsx, xlsx-populate

I am using xlsx-populate module with node.js. I am sending the workbook as a buffer, as mentioned on their site. I am using postman to hit the API and get the xlsx file as attachment. But the response I am getting has weird characters as shown below:

```
�2�N��N��+xl/drawings/drawing1.xml����0��>ٻ=C���@`ChB�M�
��M���8�̗�����ً��5��2��i
```

```
const workbook = await XlsxPopulate.fromFileAsync(filename);

// await workbook.toFileAsync(outfile);
const data = await workbook.outputAsync();

res.attachment("output.xlsx");
res.send(data);
```

When I use `await workbook.toFileAsync(outfile);` to save the file locally, everything works and I can read the file. 
But when I try to send the file to download using the commands `res.attachment("output.xlsx");` and `res.send(data);`, I get weird characters in the response to Postman.

The response headers have 11 properties which includes:

```
content-disposition -> attachment; filename="output.xlsx"
content-type -> application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
```

Similar steps to download xlsx file using express is also mentioned on the  GitHub page of `xlsx-populate` :
https://github.com/dtjohnson/xlsx-populate#serving-from-express

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the "Send and download" button in Postman, just click the up arrow on the Send button and you should see this option.

[image: Send and download]

Then when you send the request you should be prompted to download the "output.xlsx" file.

I don't think you need to make any coding changes.

Comment: It worked. But as far as I remember Postman used to prompt the user to save the file. Also would I need to make any other changes to ensure that file is automatically downloaded on front-end browser.

Comment: Maybe the behaviour in Postman changed? I seem to remember that too. I also tested this on Firefox and Chrome and the download works well, so I don't think ant changes should be necessary.